# Mapping an integral template parameter value onto a primitive type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I want to map a number to a type. For this example I'll make a function that maps a sizeof() result onto a signed primitive type.

I am wondering if there is a better way of doing what I did below in modern C++, which is to take a templated value and convert it into a type. Right now this works in converting a size to a known type, but I can't seem to find anything in the standard library that does what I want. Have I missed something?

If not, is there a better way of doing this or cleaning up this code? For example if somehow in the future we end up having 128 bit types, this wouldn't support that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <size_t S>
static constexpr auto sizeToType() {
    static_assert(S == 1 or S == 2 or S == 4 or S == 8, "Bad type size");

    if constexpr (S == 1)
        return int8_t{};
    else if constexpr (S == 2)
        return int16_t{};
    else if constexpr (S == 4)
        return int32_t{}; 
    else
        return int64_t{};
}

int main() {
    using MY_TYPE = decltype(sizeToType<2>());

    MY_TYPE myType = MY_TYPE(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEUL);

    std::cout << sizeof(MY_TYPE) << " bytes" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "MY_TYPE(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEUL) = " << myType << std::endl;
}
```

Output (as expected):

```
2 bytes
MY_TYPE(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEUL) = -2
```

Comment: whats wrong with the solution you have? Given that your code as written is only possible with modern c++, I wonder what the question is

Comment: @user463035818 As said in my post, I want to know if there is a better way to do this, or possibly something that can scale to any primitive size type if new ones are introduced (ex: `__int128` as seen [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) if supported) automatically without needing to update the code ever. I also would like to know if there's a less verbose and less brittle way of doing what I did.

Comment: even the types you use in your example are just optional and are [provided only if the implementation directly supports the type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: do we agree your solution would not support any types as size is really a poor way to get type equality? that said, you could use a tuple of supported types and find in it which one match the size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not use C++17 `if constexpr` for this, instead I'd use template specialization, as it looks more declarative to me.

Something along the following lines:

```
template<size_t S> struct SizeToType {static_assert(S != S, "Wrong size"); };

template<> struct SizeToType<1> { using type = uint8_t; };
template<> struct SizeToType<2> { using type = uint16_t; };
template<> struct SizeToType<4> { using type = uint32_t; };
template<> struct SizeToType<8> { using type = uint64_t; };

template<size_t S>
using SizeToToTypeT = typename SizeToType<S>::type;
```

Adding more types would be just adding more specializations (one-liners) here.

Comment: The primary is too close to being ill-formed NDR. It might be better to simply leave it undefined.

Comment: @StoryTeller I wanted meaningful diagnostics. But I am not sure, why would it be NDR? (Other than the type in `S == S` which I am correcting right now).

Comment: Like 90% of those cases. It's [temp.res]/8. That condition is not entirely dependant. So a clever implementation might diagnose the primary outright. It's a dark corner.

Comment: @StoryTeller it has a bunch of cases. Can you point to the one which is violated?

Comment: I'm on mobile, so I can't do it easily (cxxdraft-gen is hard to navigate). I would have done it already otherwise. I like the tabular approach.

Comment: and leave out the `static_assert()` so it can become SFINAE friendly?

Comment: @max66 matter of preference - do you want SFINAE-friendly or do you want more helpful diagnostic? Both are valid approaches depending on the end goal. Wild guess - was it you who upvoted NDR comment? If yes, may be you can explain why it is NDR?

Comment: @SergeyA - wild but correct: yes, I've up-voted the StoryTeller's comments. Explain? I can try but I'm not a language layer so take what I write with inventory benefit. IMHO it's ill-formed, NDR, according (C++11 standard, but I suppose there is the same in C++14 and C++17) point 8 in 14.6: "If no valid specialization can be generated for a template, and that template is not instantiated, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required". My sfinae-friendly suggestion is also to avoid this types of doubts.

Comment: @max66, right, but does static_assert mean that no valid specialization can be generated, though? I will ask LL question.

Comment: @SergeyA - Good idea. Yes the exact meaning of "valid specialization [...] for a template" is important, in this context, and isn't clear to me. But I prefer, when possible, avoid at all this type of problems.

Comment: @SergeyA - So, if I understand correctly, Barry interpreted that point in a way, NathanOliver interpret it in a completely different way and Yakk pointed the attention to another phrase and conclude the full program is ill-formed, NDR. Considering that all of they are far more expert than me, at this point my comment is: mayday! mayday!

Answer (score 2):

Not a great solution... but just for fun...

I propose a type traits (with helper and using to select the internal type) that, given a number (the number of bytes) and a list of types select the first type of the list with `sizeof()` greater or equal (or nothing if there is no such type)

```
template <std::size_t, typename, typename = std::true_type>
struct sizeTypeH;

template <std::size_t Dim>
struct sizeTypeH<Dim, std::tuple<>, std::true_type>
 { };  // no type found

template <std::size_t Dim, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct sizeTypeH<Dim, std::tuple<T0, Ts...>,
                 std::integral_constant<bool, (sizeof(T0) >= Dim)>>
 { using type = T0; };

template <std::size_t Dim, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct sizeTypeH<Dim, std::tuple<T0, Ts...>,
                 std::integral_constant<bool, (sizeof(T0) < Dim)>>
   : public sizeTypeH<Dim, std::tuple<Ts...>>
 { };

template <std::size_t Dim, typename ... Ts>
struct sizeType : public sizeTypeH<Dim, std::tuple<Ts...>>
 { };

template <std::size_t Dim, typename ... Ts>
using sizeType_t = typename sizeType<Dim, Ts...>::type;
```

Now another `using` that, receiving a integer, call this type traits with the ordered list of `intX_t` types

```
template <std::size_t Dim>
using intType_t = sizeType_t<Dim, std::int8_t, std::int16_t, std::int32_t,
                             std::int64_t>;
```

In my platform I have that the following `static_assert()` are verified.

```
   using t8  = intType_t<1u>;
   using t16 = intType_t<2u>;
   using t32 = intType_t<4u>;
   using t64 = intType_t<8u>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<t8, std::int8_t>{}, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<t16, std::int16_t>{}, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<t32, std::int32_t>{}, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<t64, std::int64_t>{}, "!" );
```

If, tomorrow, is introduced a `int128_t`, you can simply add it in `intType_t` `using` definition.

Attention, please: there is no guaranties that the preceding `static_assert()` are satisfied.

First of all because the standard guaranties that a byte is at least of 8 bits; but can be more that 8 bits. If a byte is of 16 bits, from

```
using t16 = intType_t<2u>;
```

you get a type of **32** bits.

Second because `intX_t` types are optionals.