# Does [temp.res]/8 in C++ standard make this program ill-formed?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Let's consider a very basic case of a template class for which only specializations are valid:

```
template<bool B>
struct OnlyTrue; // { static_assert(B != B, "Only true!"; };

template<> struct OnlyTrue<true> { static constexpr bool value = true; };

static constexpr bool b = OnlyTrue<true>::value;
```

An example above *effectively* disallows using `OnlyTrue<false>` in the program by making it incomplete. An alternative would be uncommenting `static_assert` - and making it complete, albeit uncompilable. The benefit of this approach would be that a more human-friendly diagnostic would be generated if instantiated with disallowed value. (See [Mapping an integral template parameter value onto a primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53488151/mapping-an-integral-template-parameter-value-onto-a-primitive-type/53488311?noredirect=1#comment93849450_53488311) for a bit more meaningful example of the same technique).

Now to the question - would [temp.res]/8 in latest C++ standard, in particular, 8.1:

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if: ... no valid
>   specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a
>   `constexpr if` statement within a template and the template is not
>   instantiated ...

Make the above snippet ill-formed with **no diagnostic required**?

Comment: Why would that clause trigger? There exists a valid specialization. You provided it.

Comment: but isnt `OnlyTrue<true>` one valid specialization that can be generated? The question is about the code as is (ie without the static assert), right?

Comment: Are you talking about `OnlyTrue` being possibly invalid or `b`?

Comment: Also relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/47657098/4832499