# Template: How to select smallest int type which holds n bits?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

For an own implementation of `std::bitset` (std forbidden) I used `uint_fast32_t`, since it's faster on 64bit CPUs. A review remark was to save space for small sets, e.g. bitset<6> shouldn't use 8 bytes. The waste is even more if you consider alignment in a struct.

To use C++11 is fine. I would like to elegantly select:

- Size <= 8 : uint8_t
- Size <= 16: uint16_t
- Size <= 32: uint32_t
- Size > 32: uint_fast32_t

as storage type in my class:

```
template<size_t Size>
struct BitSet {
    typedef <expression> StorageType;
    // an array of that storage type...
};
```

I can just think of rather clumsy helper templates, but maybe there is something more elegant in C++11.

Edit: to clarify: `uint_fast8_t` would be fine for the original class, the compiler may choose whatever is fast. Imagine Size==1000000. But it would be 64 bit on some machines, and when size matters in some use-cases, e.g. Size==4 it means 7 bytes would be wasted.

Comment: Why `Size > 32: uint_fast32_t`?  `uint_fast32_t` can be 32 bits wide so if I pass 64 I wouldn't want a 64 bit type returned.

Comment: after reading the title i wanted to suggest `std::bitset` ....

Comment: @NathanOliver I think that a typo (like 8 bytes should be 8 bits)

Comment: Recursive template that calls <N+1> by default and specializations for 8, 16, 32 and 64 should work

Comment: Agreed, use your own typetraits.

Comment: remotely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53488151/mapping-an-integral-template-parameter-value-onto-a-primitive-type

Comment: Are you biasing towards smallest size possible that has at least n bits, or biasing towards smallest size without loss of performance?

Comment: @NathanOliver: If I pass 64 I want the compiler to choose the fastest option. If I pass 32 I want to use only 4 bytes, not 8, even though it's a 64bit machine.

Comment: @Slava: No typo, 64bits are 8 bytes, quite a waste if you need just e.g. 4 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a helper

```
namespace detail {

    template <int overload>
    struct StorageType;

    template <>
    struct StorageType<0>{ using type = uint8_t; };

    template <>
    struct StorageType<1>{ using type = uint16_t; };

    template <>
    struct StorageType<2>{ using type = uint32_t; };

    template <>
    struct StorageType<3>{ using type = uint_fast32_t; };
}
```

We can then sum `constexpr` booleans

```
template<size_t Size>
struct BitSet {
    typedef typename detail::StorageType<(Size > 8) + (Size > 16) + (Size > 32)>::type StorageType;
    // an array of that storage type...
};
```

Answer (score 9):

Given the small selection of possible types, I'd just hardcode the conditions:

```
using StorageType = std::conditional_t<Size <=  8, uint8_t,
                    std::conditional_t<Size <= 16, uint16_t,
                    std::conditional_t<Size <= 32, uint32_t, uint_fast32_t>>>;
```

Alternatively, using a trick similar to one from @Caleth's answer:

```
using StorageType = std::tuple_element_t<(Size > 8) + (Size > 16) + (Size > 32),
                        std::tuple<uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, uint_fast32_t>>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive template class with a non-type template argument for the bit limit, and a member type alias for the corresponding integer type.

You don't need to write such template yourself though, Boost has you covered: `boost::uint_t<N>::least` (or `boost::uint_t<N>::fast` if you're not looking for the smallest, but fastest).

---

P.S. If you plan to implement the template yourself, and you want the **smallest** integer type (as per the question in the title), then you should use `std::uint_leastN_t` instead of `uint_fastN_t` or `uintN_t`. The former is not necessarily the smallest type, and the latter is not guaranteed to exist on all systems.

Furthermore `uint_fast32_t` is not guaranteed to be able to represent more bits than 32, so it is a rather poor choice for `Size > 32`. I would recommend `uint_least64_t` instead.

Comment: `std::uint_leastN_t` is not an option, as it is as small as possible, being maybe very slow to process. It should be fast for big sizes, but also small for small sizes (<=64).

Comment: `uint_fast32_t` represents at least 32 bits, which is not needed, `uint_fast8_t` would be fine. On the other hand `uint_least64_t` is slow on 32bit machines and waste for e.g. BitSet<4>.

Comment: @Borph Your question asked for smallest int; that is what `uint_leastN_t` gives you. If that's not what you want, then use `uint_fastN_t` by all means. But `uintN_t` is probably not a good choice. `uint_least64_t` being slower than `uint_fast32_t` is irrelevant if you need to represent integers larger than 32 bits.

Comment: Right, for `Size<=32` `uint_leastN_t` is wanted, with N being a template argument. For `Size>32` `uint_fast8_t` is sufficient as the performance argument takes over.

Answer (score 0):

A verbose solution with less magic. Ref: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/P2AGZ8

```
#include<cstdint>

namespace helper { namespace internal {

enum class Size {
    Uint8,
    Uint16,
    Uint32,
    UintFast32,
};

constexpr Size get_size(int s) {
    return (s <= 8 ) ? Size::Uint8:
           (s <= 16) ? Size::Uint16:
           (s <= 32) ? Size::Uint32: Size::UintFast32;
}

template<Size s>
struct FindTypeH;

template<>
struct FindTypeH<Size::Uint8> {
    using Type = std::uint8_t;
};

template<>
struct FindTypeH<Size::Uint16> {
    using Type = std::uint16_t;
};

template<>
struct FindTypeH<Size::Uint32> {
    using Type = std::uint32_t;
};

template<>
struct FindTypeH<Size::UintFast32> {
    using Type = std::uint_fast32_t;
};
}

template<int S>
struct FindType {
    using Type = typename internal::FindTypeH<internal::get_size(S)>::Type;
};
}

template<int S>
struct Myclass {
    using Type = typename helper::FindType<S>::Type;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of `constexpr if` if your compiler supports it - might be the easiest one to read. Example based on code from [here](https://github.com/jh0x/toolbox/blob/37def1c2ea9ec3013422720fd1d0fca89fc6702d/include/toolbox/BitSet.h#L15):

```
template<size_t S>
static constexpr auto _findStorageType() {
    static_assert(S > 0, "Invalid storage size");

    if constexpr (S <= sizeof(uint8_t) * CHAR_BIT) return uint8_t{};
    else if constexpr (S <= sizeof(uint16_t) * CHAR_BIT) return uint16_t{};
    else if constexpr (S <= sizeof(uint32_t) * CHAR_BIT) return uint32_t{};
    else if constexpr (S <= sizeof(uint64_t) * CHAR_BIT) return uint64_t{};
    else return __uint128_t{};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
template<std::size_t MAX_VAL>
using min_unsigned_type = std::tuple_element_t<
    bit_width(MAX_VAL), // See bellow.
    std::tuple<
         std::uint8_t,
         std::uint16_t,
         std::uint32_t,
         std::uint64_t
>>;
```

This is simply using the `bit_width`, ie. the minimum number of bits that can fit the maximum value needed to index the `std::tuple` of all the types you want to use.

C++20 has a [`std::bit_width`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_width) that is `constexpr`, but if needed it's easy to write your own version.